# an odd bug in CommonOptionsParser

Tags: clang

I am a new learner in Clang and meet an odd bug.

My code is a simple case:

```
..... 
static llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory(""); 
..... 
int main(int argc, const char **argv) 
{ 
  CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, MyToolCategory); 
  ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(), 
                 OptionsParser.getSourcePathList()); 
  tooling::MyFactory Factory; 
  Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Factory)); 
  return 0; 
}
```

but it report an very odd error when compile with clang++(my llvm&clang's version is 3.4):

```
ToolingTutorial.cpp:74:23: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser' 
  CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, MyToolCategory); 
                      ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
/home/acsa-amd2/Documents/llvm-3.4/tools/clang/include/clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h:67:3: note: candidate constructor not 
      viable: no known conversion from 'llvm::cl::OptionCategory' to 'const char *' for 3rd argument 
  CommonOptionsParser(int &argc, const char **argv, const char *Overview = 0); 
  ^ 
/home/acsa-amd2/Documents/llvm-3.4/tools/clang/include/clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h:61:7: note: candidate constructor 
      (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 3 were provided 
class CommonOptionsParser { 
      ^ 
/home/acsa-amd2/Documents/llvm-3.4/tools/clang/include/clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h:61:7: note: candidate constructor 
      (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 3 were provided 
1 error generated. 
make: *** [ToolingTutorial.o] Error 1
```

it makes no sense that the constructor is no match and the compiler mistake  'llvm::cl::OptionCategory' for  'const char *' .
Did anyone meet this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error in a tutorial, the error message says that there is something wrong with the last argument.

I have checked the official API (http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1tooling_1_1CommonOptionsParser.html) and the example given seems to use the same pattern.

But I have also checked my source files (/usr/include/clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h on Arch) and the declaration of the constructor is not the same.
My clang version is 3.4. The next version is 3.5 and I think that the official documentation
is for the 3.5.

According to the documentation in the source file of the clang 3.4 the last argument seem to be optionnal and you can use:

```
CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv);
```

After that I had no errors during the compile time.

Comment: Yes,It was the version problem.Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In the latest LLVM14, `CommonOptionsParser`'s construct functions are declared as protected or private. So, replace these functions with `create(...)`.

```
llvm::Expected<clang::tooling::CommonOptionsParser> option = CommonOptionsParser::create(argc, argv, FindDeclCategory, llvm::cl::OneOrMore, FindDeclUsage);

auto files = option->getSourcePathList();

clang::tooling::ClangTool tool(option->getCompilations(), files);

return tool.run(clang::tooling::newFrontendActionFactory<DeclFindingAction>().get());
```

Comment: Emm, but how to change existed code with`Create()`? What's meaning about `FindDeclUsage`?